# How to insert one row spacing between tiles in a tiled image using Imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, tile

I have a bunch of images that I want to tile together in one row. This can be done using Imagemagick `montage` like this

```
montage `ls tile*.png` -tile x1 -gravity west -geometry 1x1\<+0+0 out_file.png
```

However, now I want to insert one pixel of spacing after each tile. I played with `-tile-offset -1+0` for a bit but this would not change anything. Similarly, I could use `-geometry 1x1\<+1+0`, but this would introduce two pixels of spacing instead of one.

How can I do one pixel of spacing between tiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the images are a known size then you can simply do 1 pixel larger in the `-geometry` switch. So if the images are 256x256 then use `-geometry 257x256`